# Java: obtener cantidad de un producto de la Base de datos

Tags: java

estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta a hacer un programita de gestion de venta de bebidas.

Tengo una tabla llamada VENTAS_HOY que guarda que productos se vendieron, asi como su cantidad.

Me funciona, hasta que llega el punto de ingresar a la tabla algun producto que ya este.  Por ejemplo,  quiero ingresar 5 Coca Colas,  y en la tabla ya hay 2 por ejemplo.  Lo que no logro es hacer mediante algun metodo, que me devuelva el numero 2 que ya hay en la tabla, para operar con el, y despues actualizar.

La tabla tiene 3 campos: Producto, Cantidad, Precio.  (La clase Bebidas tiene un constructor, entre otros, que acepta estos 3 parametros para su instanciacion).

actualmente tengo algo asi... Pero no funciona,  o yo no logro entenderlo, siempre me devuelve 0.  (Siendo que se que en la tabla el producto ya esta y tiene cierta cantidad).

Alguien me puede ayudara como lograr que este metodo me devuelva un INT con la cantidad de un producto en la tabla VENTAS_HOY?

```
public int cantidadVenta (Bebidas vo){
 int cantidadVenta = vo.getCantidadCarrito();

 DBCon conec = new DBCon();
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(cantidad) FROM VENTAS_HOY WHERE producto = ? ";
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
     try {
            ps = conec.Connect().prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, vo.getCantidadCarrito());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()){
            cantidadVenta=rs.getInt(1);
            }
            /*
            if (rs!= null ){                
        Object[] fields = (Object[]) rs.getObject(0); 
        cantidadVenta = Integer.parseInt((String) fields[0]);
        System.out.println("DAO variable CantidadVenta en VENTAS HOY es: "+cantidadVenta);
    }
            */


        } catch(SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(DAO.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, "Error en consulta", e);
        }

 System.out.println("DAO variable CantidadVenta en VENTAS HOY es: "+cantidadVenta);
 return cantidadVenta;
}
```

Comment: En el código estás pasando a la consulta el parámetro `vo.getCantidadCarrito()` y parece que le deberías de pasar un `producto`.

Answer (score 1):

La sentencia definida espera que le informe el identificador único de un producto en particular

```
SELECT COUNT(cantidad) FROM VENTAS_HOY WHERE producto = ?
```

sin embargo al preparar los parametros la sentencia con la siguiente instrucción, no se está informando el identificador del producto sino otro dato ***vo.getCantidadCarrito()***

```
ps.setInt(1, vo.getCantidadCarrito());
```

Debes reemplazar ese parámetro por el correcto, en el código no es claro si ya tienes el identificador del producto en el objeto ***vo***, pero asumiendo que sí, entonces la instrucción debería quedar algo así:

```
ps.setInt(1, vo.getIdProducto());
```

Comment: Aún diría mas, si la tabla tiene entradas en la forma `Cocacola;2;10.0` la sentencía SQL podría pasar a ser directamente `SELECT cantidad FROM VENTAS_HOY WHERE producto = ?` Si no, estará contando cuantos productos hay que tengan el `producto` que se le pasa.